# Disable opacity on child element when parent element has opacity react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how we disable or give a different value to opacity to child inside a view or another component that has opacity in react native
for example, I have a container that is view having opacity 0.5 and there is a text component inside it, I want to give opacity 0.9 to text but it does not take the opacity , it take the parent's opacity

Comment: provide some code that you have tried. check the community standards to ask a question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't add the opacity value to View style, just give some transparency to the background color as following:

```
backgroundColor: '#00000009' // the last 2 numbers (05) refer to opacity here.
```